# SSISDB false success report

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am running a set of SSIS packages via SSISDB which are returning a overall success message even though child packages controlled by the parent package fail.

The packages consist of a parent package which calls child packages in sequence.

Is there a way to set the SSISDB report to show an overall status of failure if a child packages fail?

Comment: check FailParentOnFailure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to set FailParentOnFailure to True, on the Execute Package Task properties of the task that runs the child package.